# How to Convert MathML(stored in MS Word) to MathType using Java/XSLT?

Tags: java, xml, xslt, mathml, mathtype

I have a third party desktop application (developed in JAVA) which accepts MS Word document.

The MS word document can have mathematical formulas, which are in MathML format.
Where as, java application understands the documents containing formula of type MathType(prior to MathML representation in MS Word).

Now, the question is, **Can I convert MS Word formulas stored in MathML format into MathType format using programming?**

Note: I could convert Office MathML(OMML) to MathML(MML) using XSLT.
I am more interested to do this transformation either JAVA program or XSLT.

Comment: Where a MathML subtree has a corresponding MathType expression, *of course* you can transform one to the other.  XSLT is probably a good choice of technology for that.  If you're asking for full details of such a transform, however, then that's far too broad a question for SO.

Comment: Hi John, 
Yes, I am looking for a example/peace of XSLT which gives me a startup to convert MathML to MathType format.

Comment: The format of MathType xml is in OLEObject. I should transform MathML format into OLE Object. Can anyone have such xslt?

Answer (score 1):

The MathType SDK has some libraries that may prove useful. See [http://dessci.com/en/reference/sdk/default.htm][1]. There's no XSLT there though.

[1]: MathType Software Development Kit